# AOP interceptor to intercept all applications in same JVM

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am wondering whether it is possible to **intercept all calls** to say javax.persistence.EntityManager.flush(), across all applications running in **same JVM** (such as Glassfish domain).

Following not helping yet ;-(

```
@Aspect
public class TraceAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(@(@javax.persistence.PersistenceContext *) *)")
    public void entityManagers() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(@javax.persistence.EntityManager *.merge) && args(object)")
    public void merge(Object o) {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(@javax.persistence.EntityManager *.createQuery) && args(string)")
    public void createQuery(String s) {
    }

    @AfterReturning("entityManagers() && merge(object)")
    public void afterMerge(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
    }

    @AfterReturning("entityManagers() && createQuery(string)")
    public void afterCreateQuery(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you will need a Load-Time Weaving somehow (http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html) Than your aspect will be executed for all classes that are wowen at load time - no matter if you have their source or not

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know next to nothing about application servers/containers, but basically it should be a classloading issue. You have two options, always assuming that the classes to be intercepted are loaded only once in the JVM, not once per logical app container (in that case you would need another approach, but it would still be possible):

- Compile-time binary weaving: weave your container's JAR file(s) containing the classes to be intercepted, creating new JARs and replacing the originals by them. In this case you only need the AspectJ runtime JAR on your boot classpath in order to make it work.
- Load-time weaving: put the AspectJ weaver JAR on the boot classpath of your JVM and apply the advice to the target classes when they are loaded.